# How do I programmatically use tor

Tags: node.js, tor

My tor is connected to `127.0.0.1:9051`, Its said that it not an http proxy so how can I really connect to websites programmatically using it (preferably node.js)?
([Trying to connect using http GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32jU5.png))

Like is there a specific way of sending requests?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Axios for request and set proxy to TOR SOCKS proxy.
Like below

```
const axios = require('axios');
const SocksProxyAgent = require('socks-proxy-agent');
const proxyOptions = `socks5://$127.0.0.1:9050`;
const httpsAgent = new SocksProxyAgent(proxyOptions);
const baseUrl = 'https://example.com'
const client = axios.create({baseUrl, httpsAgent});
client.get('/something').then(res => res.data);
```

Comment: Is this still working?

Answer (score 0):

To the people who are looking for an updated answer here what's working for me. Make sure your `tor` instance running on another terminal tab or in the background.

It's just a regular `axios` setup but we need to pass the `httpsAgent` parameter created by `socks-proxy-agent` library.

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const { SocksProxyAgent } = require('socks-proxy-agent')

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const httpsAgent = new SocksProxyAgent('socks://127.0.0.1:9050')

    const result = await axios({
      httpsAgent,
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://api.ipify.org'
    })

    console.log(result.data)
    // 185.220.101.68
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
}

run()
```